# Combine several libraries to one new library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

I have multiple small libraries with the same column structure. Is there any fast way to combine all these singular libraries to one new library?

Comment: As you say thay they got the same columns/content type I assume that each document have some properties/metadata that need to be set as well? I think that you need to add more details to your question.

Comment: @Christoffer: no, the libraries have just the same structure. The new librariy must have 3 new columns more than all the existing libraries to differentiate the data . But at the moment all libraries have the same amount of columns and the columns have the same names.

Comment: I understand, but does the column holds value for each document? In other words, the data must remain the same?

Comment: Yes, there is data in the columns to be transferred.

Comment: SharePoint migration tool might suit your needs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool